# signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN) - how to debug

Tags: android, sigbus

I have a weird crash - the crash reproduces almost only on Samsung Galaxy Tab A (with S Pen) devices, on a release build.

The stack-trace is very short, and consist only of two relevant lines -
/lib/arm/my-jni.so (my_func_loop+1662)
/lib/arm/my-jni.so (first_function+694)

I checked those lines using addr2line, but I don't think the problem is really there. It's probably a memory problem somewhere else. So how can I debug this? I don't have any info on where the problem is, so is there any way to release the version with some additional flags which will help to catch the problematic location? For example, GCC has a sanitizer that can help catch those bugs.